# What is consistency map (confidence map)?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, point-cloud-library

Can anybody help me to explain what is consistency map (confidence map) in computer vision? and is there any formula or built-in function to calculate it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Confidence map** is your resultant knowledge, using a priori information & and an iteration of an algorithm. Prediction & measurement update style visual tracking algorithms are great examples. From wiki (mean-shift):

> The mean shift algorithm can be used for visual tracking. The simplest
>   such algorithm would create a confidence map in the new image based on
>   the color histogram of the object in the previous image, and use mean
>   shift to find the peak of a confidence map near the object's old
>   position. The confidence map is a probability density function on the
>   new image, assigning each pixel of the new image a probability, which
>   is the probability of the pixel color occurring in the object in the
>   previous image. A few algorithms, such as ensemble tracking,
>   CAMshift, expand on this idea.

As far as I know, the term **consistency map,** on the other hand, is used in image registration problems, in general. A voxel needs to be "photo-consistent" to be rendered(modeled) in 3d. From wiki again (photo-consistency):

> In computer vision photo-consistency determines whether a given voxel
>   is occupied. A voxel is considered to be photo consistent when its
>   color appears to be similar to all the cameras that can see it. Most
>   voxel coloring or space carving techniques require using photo
>   consistency as a check condition in Image-based modeling and rendering
>   applications.

**EDIT:** OpenCV has built-in kalman filter, mean-shift and camshift algorithms. It also has a [3D rendering API](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your explanation. Actually, I want to find a consistency map in image registration problem. First I have point cloud data (pcd file) which captured from kinect then I have to use PCL registration to register those file. So I have to find the consistency map in order to apply Background Subtraction to find the movement object which occurred in the registered-data. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to get those consistency map from my PCD file.